# how to create a nuget package for UWP custom control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, nuget

I have this user control that I want to pack into a nuget package. my xaml and xaml.cs files are in a blank uwp app which I succesfully packed into a nuget package. The problem is that I cannot really reference it if I install the nuget in another project. Any idea how I should build this buget that? I read from MS's tutorial that I should probably use templated control or something like that but how I can encode my xaml in that case. Really need some advice.

xaml:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="StickControl.StickControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:StickControl"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="Stick"></Grid>
    <ListView Width="auto" Height="auto" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items,Mode=OneWay}">

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Foreground="Black"  Text="{Binding menuText,Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;


namespace StickControl
{
    public sealed partial class Stick : Page
    {

        public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> Items
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<MenuItem>)GetValue(TitleListProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TitleListProperty, value); RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleListProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<MenuItem>), typeof(StickControl), null);

        public List<string> Titles
        {
            get { return (List<string>)GetValue(TitlesProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TitlesProperty, value); RaisePropertyChanged();
                if (Items.Count < Titles.Count)
                {
                    int dif = Titles.Count - Items.Count;
                    for (int i = 0; i < dif; i++)
                        Items.Add(new MenuItem());
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < Titles.Count; i++)
                {
                    Items[i].menuText = Titles[i];
                }
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitlesProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Titles", typeof(List<string>), typeof(StickControl), null);


        public Stick()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Items = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();

        }

        public void Remove(int count)
        {
            for (int i = Items.Count - 1; i > Items.Count - count - 1; i--)
                Items.RemoveAt(i);
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }


        public class MenuItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private string menu_text;
            public string menuText
            {
                get { return menu_text; }
                set { menu_text = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
            }
            public MenuItem()
            {
                menuText = "(empty title)";
            }
            public MenuItem(string title)
            {
                menuText = title;
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name = null)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? I think the document in Zivkan's answer is what you're looking for, you can check if it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link that @logeshpalani98 gave only works for SDK style projects (used by, but not limited to, .NET Core and .NET Standard). UWP projects do not support SDK style projects yet. However NuGet's docs do have another page titled [Create UWP packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-uwp-packages). Unfortunately it's much more difficult than packing an SDK style project, but it should get you started on the right track.

Another option is to find an existing package with UWP controls, for example [Telerik.UI.for.UniversalWindowsPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telerik.UI.for.UniversalWindowsPlatform/) and figure out how it works (what files are in what directories), then create your own package copying the structure.

Comment: Ok thank you. My problem is exactly that I can’t follow ‘Create UWP packages’ quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Go Packages and Enter your **Nuget details** then right click the project and Select **Pack** then check **Generate Nuget Package**. Go Project folder the .Nuspec file is available there.

More [Details](https://github.com/NuGet/learn.microsoft.com-nuget/blob/master/docs/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio.md)